# Angular: Make div fill remaining horizontal space with opening and closing sidenav (Angular Materials)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, flexbox

**Introduction**

I have an page the presents a Angular Material sidenav that can open and close. I place that component in a div that also brings in a workspace component (varies depending on the page) that should take up the remaining space on the page. It needs to be dynamic in light of the fact the sidenav is able to open and close.

*sidedraw.component.html*

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav
      class="sidenav"
      #sidenav
      mode="side"
      [(opened)]="isShown"
      (opened)="isShown = true"
      (closed)="isShown = false"
    >
      Sidenav content
    </mat-sidenav>
  
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <p>
          <button class="toggleButton" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
            <img *ngIf="isShown" src="../../../assets/icons/arrow-left.png" />
            <img *ngIf="!isShown" src="../../../assets/icons/arrow-right.png" />
          </button>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet='workspaceComponent'></ng-container>
</div>
```

The `workspaceComponent` on the second last line is determined by:

*sidedraw.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EstimatesworkspaceComponent } from 'src/app/workspaces/estimatesworkspace/estimatesworkspace.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidedraw',
  templateUrl: './sidedraw.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidedraw.component.css'],
})
export class SidedrawComponent {
  isShown = true;
  workspaceComponent = EstimatesworkspaceComponent;
}
```

Later on I plan to make the `workspaceComponent` more dynamic but I am not there yet.

**Problem**

I can't get the `workspaceComponent` to fill the remainder of the page with no matter what I try.

My component template and relevant style sheets for now are as follows:

*estimatesworkspace.component.html*

```
<div class='request-container'> 
    Please enter the name of the business whose value you would like an estimate for
</div>
```

*estimatesworkspace.component.css*

```
.request-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That code results in the following displayed:

[image]

I have tried `display: flex` and `flex-grow: grow` or `flex-grow:1` everywhere I can think of and can't seem to get a solution. Any suggestions will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Give a stackblitz or code sandbox example to look at your problem.
I think that button should be absolute in my opinion to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

workspace component should be inside side-nav-content

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <button class="toggleButton" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
            <img *ngIf="isShown" src="../../../assets/icons/arrow-left.png" />
            <img *ngIf="!isShown" src="../../../assets/icons/arrow-right.png" />
          </button>
        
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet='workspaceComponent'></ng-container>
    </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, all it did was place the `workingComponent` below the open/close button which is not what I want...

Comment: ok but this is the correct way, you have to give open close button absolute position

Comment: content must be in ma-sidenav-content

Comment: let me know if giving absolute position to button and some styles for positioning it left and top works